# Mashiach arriving upon the observance of Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, messiah

Does anyone have a source for the suggestion that:

> If all Israel respected the Sabbath if only one single day, the Messiah would come immediately, for it is written: “Today if you were to listen to his voice”?

Comment: Where did you find that quotation?

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/moshiach/article_cdo/aid/101681/jewish/Hastening-Mashiach.htm#footnote5a101681

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](http://www.chabad.org/library/moshiach/article_cdo/aid/101681/jewish/Hastening-Mashiach.htm#footnote5a101681) but it doesn't exactly say the logic you listed in the question

Shemot Rabba 25:121; Yerushalmi, Ta’anit 1:10 “Though I have set a limit to ‘the end,’ that it will happen in its time regardless of whether they will do teshuvah or not… the scion of David (Mashiach) will come if they keep just one Shabbat, because the Shabbat is equivalent to all the mitzvot.”

Comment: א"ר לוי אילו היו ישראל משמרין שבת אחת כתיקנה מיד היה בן דוד בא מאי טעמא (שמות טז) ויאמר משה אכלוהו היום כי שבת היום לה' וגומר חד יום.  ואומר (ישעיהו ל) בשובה ונחת תושעון בשובה ונייח תתפרקון: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2901.htm

Answer (score 4):

[די באקאנטע גמרא אין מסכת שבת (קיח ע"א)אמר רשב"י אלמלא שמרו ישראל שני שבתות מיד הן נגאלים, שנאמר כה אמר ה' לסריסים וכו' מה כתיב בתריה, והביאותים א](http://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=605814&sid=eae96b464693bac868f990eae6cc8cce#p605814)

The gemoro in shabbos 118A says if two shabbosim are kept  the geula will come.

Comment: I think the idea is that they all kept the first shabbat, and so there is only one shabbat left to keep.

Comment: @Menachem I heard the same explanation for that Gemara, though IMHO it doesn't really seem to be saying that

Comment: No source for this, but I recall something about how it would now take 2 shabbats, since we are in galut all over the world, and so not everyone can physically keep shabbas at exactly the same time.

Comment: @Matt I heard once that the two are Shabbat and Shemita (שבת הארץ). Makes much more sense because 1) it's not just doing a certain mitzva a random number of times 2) Shemitta is mentioned in the Tochekha (ותרץ את שבתותיה) as something that we need Galut for not keeping.

Comment: @DoubleAA the Radak heard that too, in the name of his father. I also like that comparison, but I have to admit that it still seems a bit strange to me that in the context of discussing the many rewards for keeping Shabbos Bereishis, suddenly one use of the word "Shabbos" is also meant to refer to Shemitta. But I'm not one to argue on R. Moshe Kimhi

Comment: @Matt Where is that Radak?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeshayahu 56:4 (the pasuk quoted by the Gemara there)

Comment: @הנערהזה Reb Noson MiNemirov, in the [Likutei Halachos Hilchos Sefirah 1](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60190&st=&pgnum=607), has a beautiful explanation for the two-Shabbos concept, explaining what it means that one Shabbos has been kept and what the second one is.

Answer (score 4):

I found the Gemorrah to be Shabbos 118B not 118A, Rashi in Bamidbar, at the end of Shelach says that the Jews had already kept one Shabbos, before the story of the Mekoshesh Etzim - wood gatherer, so it makes sense to say that this would be meaning - should the Jews keep one more Shabbos (a total of two), the Geula would come.

Comment: Hey YBK, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for your answer (+1). You might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. I hope to see you around!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a misread of the end of [Yerushalmi Taanis 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Ta'anit.3b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> ר' אחא בשם ר' תנחום בי ר' חייה אילו ישראל עושין תשובה יום א' מיד היה בן דוד בא מ"ט [תהילים צה ז] היום אם בקולו תשמעו א"ר לוי אילו היו ישראל משמרין שבת אחת כתיקנה מיד היה בן דוד בא מאי טעמא [שמות טז כה] ויאמר משה אכלוהו היום כי שבת היום לה' וגומר חד יום. ואומר [ישעי' ל טו] בשובה ונחת תושעון בשובה ונייח תתפרקון:

The Gemara says that if they would Teshuva it would come that day based on the Pasuk that says “Today if you were to listen to his voice” Then immediately afterwards it says that if they would keep one Shabbos they would be redeemed based on other Pesukim.

See also [Shemos Rabbah 25:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.25.12?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) where the mistake also could have came from although its slightly less likely.