# One Shabbos or two?

Tags: shabbat, messiah, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

Yerushalmi Taanis 1:1 says:

> א"ר לוי אילו היו ישראל משמרין שבת אחת כתיקנה מיד היה בן דוד בא
>
> R. Levi said: If Israel kept one Shabbos correctly, the son of David would immediately come.

But [Bavli Shabbos 118b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.118b.4?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=he) says:

> אמר רבי יוחנן משום רבי שמעון בן יוחי: אלמלי משמרין ישראל שתי שבתות כהלכתן ־ מיד נגאלים
>
> R. Yochanan said in the name of R. Shimon ben Yochai: If Israel kept two Shabbasos according to the halachah, they would be redeemed immediately.

What is the difference here? Is there a significant difference from Moshiach coming and being redeemed? Is there a difference in the level of "correctness"?

Comment: Maybe they just both want us to keep Shabbat.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28811/mashiach-arriving-upon-the-observance-of-shabbat/28812#comment70320_28813

Comment: I think Mordechai Ben David paskens like the Yerushalmi here

Answer (score 2):

I heard along time ago that the explanation is that we only need to keep one Shabbos correctly like the gemara Yerushalmi says, but 'correctly' means that it must follow six days of work, as the posuk ([Shemos 20,9-10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k0220.htm#9)) says: ששת ימים תעבוד ועשית כל-מלאכתך, ויום השביעי שבת. And this itself can only be done if we keep the preceding Shabbos so that there will be exactly six days of work and not more.

Thus, the teaching in the gemara Bavli is an elaboration of the teaching of the gemara Yerushalmi, that we must keep "one Shabbos correctly" by keeping "two Shabbasos according to the halachah", and thus are saying the same thing.

Comment: This explanation is recorded [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48286&st=&pgnum=27).

Answer (score 0):

maybe shabbat in Jerusalem is more powerful than shabbat in bavel. once read by Rabbi Beniyahu Shmueli that this statement refers to the power of shabbat - that if one keeps it properly and sanctifies it (presumably with limud hatorah), his whole coming week will be different and memayla he will do teshuva

Comment: How does your second sentence support your first sentence?

Comment: point is that shabbat helps a person do teshuva if kept properly. perhaps this effect is stronger in israel